# Is there a way to tell Doxygen to ignore (all) namespaces?

Tags: namespaces, doxygen

Just about everything in my documentation ends up with the *namespace*:: prefix in front of it. (where *namespace* is the name of my namespace)

Is there a way to have the documentation generated without the namespace part?

For example:

> my_namespace::myclass::member

becomes:

> myclass::member

It would make everything more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the answer was simple: you have to set `HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES` to `YES` in the configuration file.

Comment: The only problem with this is that it also causes class scope names to be hidden, not just namespace scope names. In other words `my_namespace::myclass::member` becomes just `member`. This may not be a problem, but it *can* cause ambiguities especially when there are nested classes. For instance `superclass::subclass` becomes just `subclass` so there is no longer any indication in the documentation that `subclass` is nested within `superclass`.

Comment: True, but thankfully neither of those are problems with my project.

Comment: Does not work (changes nothing), at least with Python files (Doxygen sees Python modules as namespaces).

Comment: … does not work, *with functions* (forget to give this clarification)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but if anyone comes looking again.

You can set SHOW_NAMESPACES to NO in configuration file.

It is also in DoxyWizard, Expert tab under Build topic.

Comment: This just disables the "Namespaces" page. From the documentation: _Set the SHOW_NAMESPACES tag to NO to disable the generation of the Namespaces page._